# How to inherit __del__ function

Tags: python, inheritance, del

I am reading the Python Essential Reference 4th ed. and I cannot figure out how to fix a problem in the following code

```
class Account(object):
    num_accounts = 0

    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        Account.num_accounts += 1

    def __del__(self):
        Account.num_accounts -= 1

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.balance += amt

    def withdraw(self, amt):
        self.balance -= amt

    def inquire(self):
        return self.balance

class EvilAccount(Account):    
    def inquire(self):
        if random.randint(0,4) == 1:
            return self.balance * 1.1
        else:
            return self.balance

ea = EvilAccount('Joe',400)
```

If I understand correctly, the ea object goes out of scope when the program ends and the inherited `__del__` function should be called, correct? I receive a `'NoneType' object has no attribute num_accounts` in `__del__`. Why doesn't it complain earlier then in the `__init__` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Warning**: Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. **Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down** (e.g. the import machinery shutting down). For this reason, `__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered why this happened, but as to what you should do instead, try this:

```
import weakref
class classproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return self.f(owner)

class Account(object):
    _active = weakref.WeakSet()

    @classproperty
    def num_accounts(self):
        return len(Account._active)

    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        Account._active.add(self)

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.balance += amt

    def withdraw(self, amt):
        self.balance -= amt

    def inquire(self):
        return self.balance

>>> Account.num_accounts
0
>>> a = [Account('a', 0), Account('b', 0)]
>>> Account.num_accounts
2
>>> a.pop()
<__main__.Account object at 0x02F8D650>
>>> Account.num_accounts # Interactive session is holding onto the popped account in '_'
2
>>> Account.num_accounts # but now it has gone.
1
```

So instead of counting how many instances exist, just keep a collection of all the current instances. The `WeakSet` won't prevent them being destroyed so it will accurately track only the instances that are still alive.

Do be aware though that it is very easy for instances to stick around after you think you've lost them: if anything throws an exception then all the local variables in the stack frame will remain alive until the next exception is thrown. In this case you probably also want an explicit `close()` method that you can use when someone closes the account and that explicitly removes the instance from the active set.

Answer (score 1):

When `ea` goes out of scope, you have no control of how the memory is released. It appears that `Account` is a reference to `None` at this stage

Why do you think you need a `__del__` method at all?

Comment: I am learning python, so I don't know if I should include __del__ in my programs...I guess this function hasn't been useful for you? How else would you count instatiated objects of a class without a class variable?

Comment: Also, even if ea is garbage collected and no objects exist...why can I not use the class name to access one of its variables? Isn't this possible in python?

Comment: @Kokas : this is documented, cf my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When the interpreter exits, the `Account` reference is removed before the `EvilAccount()` instance is reaped. As a result, `Account` is now `None.

One workaround would be to use `type(self)` instead of a direct reference to the class name, but that would make the count *per class*, so `EvilAccount` would have it's own counter:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    # ...
    type(self).num_accounts += 1

def __del__(self):
    type(self).num_accounts -= 1
```

The other alternative is to check if `Account` still exists when `__del__` is invoked; simply catch the exception:

```
def __del__(self):
    try:
        Account.num_accounts -= 1
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # Account has already been reaped
```